# Better Priorization of SE Material?

Tags: discussion

SE is like a priorization engine. It consists of many ways to filter stuff, social ways and non-social ways. What are the social ways and the non-social ways? Could we somehow make this even better? Ideas?

Priorization here means things such as making things more accessible and many other things.

Comment: "Stars are mean to prioritize stuff." Where did you find that asserted? At least for Questions on the main site, the star represents "favourites". I use it only as a way to keep track of questions and answers I may want to go back to later.

Comment: I recommend that you avoid the "pony" tag; I find it rather  whimsical, and not useful for search purposes.

Comment: Can't we just close this question?

Comment: I'm not seeing stars, I don't know what a newsletter is, and I have no idea what hhh is rabbiting on about, but I suppose it is harmless.

Comment: @hhh: I did not upvote or downvote the post, nor did I make any comment about your idea. My comment was just intended to be a helpful suggestion... [I am making this clarification because you seem to think I downvoted you, and worse, you are apparently worried that I made "personal downvotes".]

Comment: **PROPOSING CLOSING** This has gathered so much spam from respected users that it looks seriously that this thread should be closed to make it more precise, people are diverting attention by upvoting totally irrelevant answer. They clearly care less about trying to make things better. Now this thread looks like personal attack rather than discussing `"priorization"`.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer to the posted question. This is a poll for whether someone should go in and delete the [pony](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pony) tag; only the asker of the current question uses this tag, essentially as an excuse to legitimize his/her highly speculative questions. Please vote with the arrows on the left.

Comment: this is a red-herring -1, this thread was meant as `"discussion"`. Please, open a new question if you want to remove a label. And what is wrong with arrogant questions? Every now-and-then arrogant questions are excellent ice-breakers. I find it dangerous that one even suggests to only have certain type of qs, variety is a strength. If you spent some time in investigating the problems with stars, you would probably have very different answer. Also, if you have read the newsletter, you may find a room for improvement to make more user-centric `"newsletters"`. One can always improve!

Comment: "what is wrong with arrogant questions" - are you serious?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are suggesting the creation of a newsletter that will be emailed out on a regular basis. I'm pretty sure there is already something like this that includes unanswered questions, hot questions, etc.

But if you want to see something new/better, maybe you should

> Create a blog, write the newsletter, and link to it on your user page(s).

Then, when the newsletter blog becomes a smash hit, you might be contacted by the bigwigs and asked to combine forces.

Until then, good luck. And hire a native English speaker to write for you. You'll thank me later.

Answer (score -1):

I outline here some ways prioritize things. The first form of priorisation is of course voting and then stars. If down-votes, something should be done to understand why -- sometimes totally irrelevant things or misunderstandings, perhaps like here with this question. Perhaps, people cannot understand the abstract terms such as priorization or original question with too much of information, anyway now short summary below.

**Chat**

> - Room > Create new bookmark
> - stars
> - flag

**Main site**

> - voting: upvotes, downvotes
> - commens
> - flag

**Outside or locally**

> - RSS feeds but computationally expensive so impossible to get for every small topic
> - newsletters [here](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=math.stackexchange.com) and for example [here](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=math.stackexchange.com)
> - blogs **[I think mostly clutter, currently]**
> - wikis
> - Data SE [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/)
> - APIs to attract third-party contributions